# How can I create separate time.sleeps in Python?

Tags: python

I'm new to Python.

```
import time
import random
daily = ("/daily")
ten = ("/ten")
hourly = ("/hourly")
while hourly == "/hourly":
    print("TYPE_HOURLY")
    time.sleep(3605)

while ten == "/ten":
    print("TYPE_TEN")
    time.sleep(605)

while daily == "/daily":
    print("TYPE_DAILY")
    time.sleep(86500)
```

Forgive my code; this is my first time ever coding. I'm trying to having separate timers go off for daily, ten, and hourly. Currently it is running only hourly and then "sleeping". How would I fix this?

I expect it to run all three of them at once and then sleeping for 3605 seconds, 605 seconds and 86500 seconds depending on what amount of time I specified.

Comment: You might want to just use the standard library [`sched`](https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/sched.html#module-sched) module, or at least study its source. The trick is to sleep for the shortest duration you need to, work on something, then figure out how long to sleep until the next task you need to work on.

Comment: Those while's will always be true, but I'd recommend starting at the Python basics, and then work your way up to threading.

Comment: This script only runs each line/iteration in series (not parallel). It's going to go into that first `while` loop and execute each line in sequence, pausing for 3605 seconds before looping again over and over and over again as there is no logic that causes it to exit the loop. Even if it it exited, it would just go to the next loop, iterate and sleep, over and over again. Using `time.sleep()` and running code that is single-threaded like you are doing will never get you to a solution. Instead you likely want this code to schedule an event (or three events, really) on your system.

Comment: You never change the value of `hourly` in the first while loop, so the first while loop never finishes executing (as pointed out by others). If you really wanted to do this, you could try using [apscheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/master?badge=3.x), but I agree with @0stone0 about starting with the basics.

Comment: To improve your code, you could also take out the parentheses when defining the variables, and you don't need to import `random` for this code to run.

Answer (score 1):

```
import time
import threading

def print_and_sleep(message, sleep_time):
    while True:
        print(message)
        time.sleep(sleep_time)

# Create threads for each timer
hourly_thread = threading.Thread(target=print_and_sleep, args=("TYPE_HOURLY", 3605))
ten_thread = threading.Thread(target=print_and_sleep, args=("TYPE_TEN", 605))
daily_thread = threading.Thread(target=print_and_sleep, args=("TYPE_DAILY", 86500))

# Start the threads
hourly_thread.start()
ten_thread.start()
daily_thread.start()

# Wait for all threads to complete
hourly_thread.join()
ten_thread.join()
daily_thread.join()
```

This code defines a function that prints a message and sleeps for a specified amount of time. It creates a thread for each timer using the threading.Thread class, starts the threads, and waits for them to complete. The program will keep running until stopped.